# If-then loop for sub-directories, if the lines in the file are more than 2

Tags: bash, if-statement, directory

A directory contains 30 sub-directories (all end with _g). In each sub-directory, a file named `report.txt` exists. I need to loop for all sub-directories and execute statement one if the lines in the file `report.txt` are greater than 2, or statement two if less than 2.

I tried using this script, but I am not getting the exact output.

```
#!/bin/bash
File=report.txt
for g in *_g;
if ((awk 'END{print NR}' $g/"$File" > 2)); then
echo "$g:";
    Statement 1 "$g"/report.txt
echo "------------------";
else 
echo "$g:";
    Statement 2 "$g"/report.txt
echo "------------------";
fi
done
```

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Please provide an example of report.txt. It is not clear to me what "f the lines in the file report.txt are greater than 2, or statement two if less than 2." means.

Comment: What if there are exactly 2 lines?

Answer (score 3):

You can test the line numbers like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="report.txt"

for f in *_g/"$filename"; do
    if [ $(wc -l < "$f") -gt 2 ]; then 
        echo "inside statement 1 for directory ${f%/*}"
        # do stuff
    else
        echo "inside statement 2 for directory ${f%/*}"
        # do stuff
    fi
done
```

---

In case of large input files, we want to test the line number without counting to the end of the file, for perfomance reasons, so here are some alternatives:

---

- Using bash-builtin `mapfile`, we read only 3 first lines. (by Léa Gris)

  ```
   mapfile -n3 <"$f"; if [ ${#MAPFILE[@]} -gt 2 ]; then
  ```

---

- Using `sed` (by @Tomi Ollila)

  ```
    if sed -n 3q1 "$f"; then
  ```

this `sed` exits with status 0 if file has 0,1 or 2 lines, or else quits with `status 1` on line 3.

---

- Or using `head` to exit after reading the 3rd line.

  ```
    if [ $(head -3 "$f" | wc -l) -gt 2 ]; then
  ```

Comment: or without `wc` but only shell built-in: `if { read;read;read;} <"$f"; then`, or bash specific `mapfile -n3 <"$f"; if [ ${#MAPFILE[@]} -gt 2 ]; then`

Comment: without wc (i.e. not scanning whole (potentially million-line file), one could use GNU sed -- `if sed -n 3q1 "$f"; then ...`

Answer (score 0):

I am replacing my original answer which used `find`. That answer could not handle spaces in directory or file names correctly.

This example also creates some directories and files for testing.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p 01_g 02_g "0 03_g"

touch 01_g/report.txt

cat <<EOF > 02_g/report.txt
one line
EOF

cat <<EOF > "0 03_g/report.txt"
one line
two line
EOF

for FILE in *_g/report.txt
do
  LINE_COUNT=$(wc -l "$FILE" | cut -d' ' -f1)
  if [ "$LINE_COUNT" == 0 ]
  then
    echo "$FILE: The file is empty."
  fi
  if [ "$LINE_COUNT" == 1 ]
  then
    echo "$FILE: The file has one line."
  fi
  if [ "$LINE_COUNT" == 2 ]
  then
    echo "$FILE: The file has two lines."
  fi
done
```